# Python: logic comparater based on dictionary values

Tags: python

I have the following 'dictionary':

```
a = {"one":(10, 11.25), "two":(11, 12.25), "three":(12, 13.25)}
```

I would like to build an 'if statement' based on on the first value of each pair (i.e. in this example I'm comparing 10, 11, 12).

How would I go about doing so?

I've been playing around with the 'a.values()' function but that lists all the values. I would like to iterate through each value and verify they are positive.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`all`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#all) with a generator:

```
if all(v[0] > 0 for v in a.values()):
```

Answer (score 0):

Small and bit easier solution

```
a = {"one":(10, 11.25), "two":(11, 12.25), "three":(-12, 13.25)}

for x,y in a.iteritems():
    print "Number is ",y[0]
    if y[0] > 0:
        print "Positive"
    else:
        print "Negative"
```

Output:

```
Number is  -12
Negative
Number is  11
Positive
Number is  10
Positive
```